# Replacement for urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a set of 50 urls...and from each url, i am retrieving some data using urllib2. The procedure I am following (including setting cookies for each url) goes as follows:

```
urls = ['https://someurl', 'https://someurl', ...]
vals = []

for url in urls:
   req2 = urllib2.Request(url)
   req2.add_header('cookie', cookie)
   response = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
   data = response.read()
   vals.append(json.loads(data))
```

So, basically I am retrieving data from all these urls and dumping it in vals list. This entire procedure for 50 urls takes around 15.5 to 20 seconds. I need to know if there is any other python library through which I can do the same operation but in a more faster way..or if you guys can suggest any other faster way of approaching this issue using urllib2, then it'll be fine as well. Thanks.

Comment: You should try using `requests`. It makes a lot of these things easier to manage. (Note that it won't resolve *performance* problems in that way, just make for much better code.)

Comment: Chris, can you elaborate with any single example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of `urllib2` won't be the limiting factor here, most of the time it will be waiting for TCP connections or for the remote server to respond.

Use of Python's [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module is fairly straightforward, but you could also use the threading module.

The [multiprocessing.Pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) could be used like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
# Use the following if you prefer to use threads over processes.
# from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

urls = ['https://someurl', 'https://someurl', ...]

def download_json(url):
    req2 = urllib2.Request(url)
    req2.add_header('cookie', cookie)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
    data = response.read()
    return json.loads(data)

pool = Pool()
vals = pool.map(download_json, urls)
```

Comment: This works pretty well..but not a big difference..but appreciate it :-) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So if 15-20 secs are costly there are couple of things you can try :

1. using threading with urllib2 itself . example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472515/python-urllib2-urlopen-is-slow-need-a-better-way-to-read-several-urls)
2. you can try pycurl .( not sure about performance improvement)
3. Once I used subprocess.Popen to run the curl command and get the response from URL in json format. I used it for calling different URLS in parallel and grabing the response as they arrive using communicate method of Popen object.

Comment: Thanks so much..every point you mentioned, sir, is a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

`urllib2` is pretty fast (20 seconds for 50 urls isn't this slow). It takes some time to connect to the resource.

What you want to do is [multithreading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm).

Comment: hmm..I read an example of with Queue class and multiprocessing module..just wondering how that can be implemented?